# Ping app not working when added to Google Play

Tags: java, android, ping

I have an app on Google Play that works on my phone when using it as a remote testing device but when I upload it to the Play Store and then download it onto my phone it wont work it fails to transmit any packets.

See code below, I dont know what the problem is i've been scratching my head all day perhaps a permissions issue?

```
package com.example.dale.whatismyip;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


/**
 * Created by Dale on 22/01/2017.
 */

public class PingActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private EditText pingEdit;
    private String pingVal;
    private TextView finalResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ping);

        finalResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        pingEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);


        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finalResult.setText("");
                pingVal = pingEdit.getText().toString();
                if(pingVal.contains(".") && pingVal.length() > 6)
                {
                    PingTest runner = new PingTest();
                    runner.execute();
                }
                else
                {
                    finalResult.setText("Invalid Address");
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private class PingTest extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        private String res;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                boolean sudo = false;
                String cmd = "/system/bin/ping -c 4 -w 4 " + pingVal;
                Process p;
                if(!sudo)
                    p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                else{
                    p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", cmd});
                }
                BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                String s;
                res = "";
                while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                    // CODE TO DO - create an array and populate it
                    System.out.println(res += s + "\n");
                }
                p.destroy();
                return res;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
            // CODE TO DO - pass this method both an array of type string and a string
            // then do a while loop through it whilst the array is populated and set the value of the textview to the strings
            finalResult.setText(result);

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue sorted.

The code itself was fine but the power saving feature on android stops the ping functionality as it disables background network usage.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is such a suggestion but are you testing your phone through a computer? is the phone connected through a usb to a computer?

and could you print a toast to see what's going on in `doInBackground`

I can't find anything wrong in your code.

Comment: Thanks for that it was testing through the PC via usb using android studio, I decided to upload it to the playstore as a beta application and made a few changes and now its started working.

Comment: okay that's great ! . you probably used the computers network . if I answered your question please mark it.

Comment: I did start working but now it's broken I'm not sure what the problem is here, I didn't touch any code I left it overnight

Comment: check the connection, I remember I once had a similar issue with connecting to a local database through USB . If you are still doing that make sure your pc / local host can detect it.check this out in chrome browser url:
chrome://inspect/#devices

Comment: Thanks Rima, I've ran further tests and it works when connected through USB but not when I take it out of USB

Comment: that's great :D . No problem glad I could help.